# Checking free space under specific directory

Tags: linux, mount, lvm, path, disk

## Introduction

In Gnu/Linux we have some mount-points, like:

```
/mountpoint1
/xyz/abc
/root
etc.
```

It is possible that files and directories under `/mountpoint1` belongs to another volume (doesn't matter whether physical or logical (let's say LVM)) than files and dir under `/xyz/abc`.   That's something like idea of mountpoints.

## My question is:

Is it possible to check free space under `/mountpoint1`?  In other words how many files and directories (obviously in B/KB/MB/GB... unit)  I can write **under** `/mountpoint1`.

Is there any way to do it?

It seems to be slightly strange, however, is it possible to check **free space of directory/path**?

Comment: Maybe `df --help` or `du --help` ? For example: `df -h /mountpoint1` or  `du -sh /mountpoint1`

Comment: Is your question "How do I get the total free space of all volumes recursively under a mount-point?"

Answer (score 1):

It is the partition, volume group, or logical volume that contains the space, not the path. You can run `du -sh` `or df -h` but the first will just show you the space that the path itself is using and the second is a bit misleading because it will show what's available for the entire partition or volume group which contains the path. If that suits your needs, then use it.

Otherwise, to see the space including what available as well as the total size and how much is being used for the disk, partitions, physical volumes, volume groups, or logical volumes, you'll have to do that with:

```
df -h
```

That shows the total space, available space, and usage of the filesystems that are mounted. As I stated above, running it directly against the path will give the total space of where it is mounted which is the same that you'll get from just running it by itself.

```
pvs
pvdisplay
```

Those commands will show the total and availabe space of the physical volumes.

```
vgs
vgdisplay
```

Those commands show the total space and free space of the volume group(s).

```
lvs
lvdisplay
```

Those commands show the total space and free space of the logical volumes.

```
fdisk -l
```

That will show the disks and partitions including what's used and available in the form of the block size and where they begin and end.

```
parted
print free
```

Using the first and then the second in the console will show the block size of the partitions including the start and end points and the free space.

Comment: I would like to check: `How many bytes I can write under `/tmp`. `df -h /tmp` is ok? It seems to me that it provides only estimation.

Answer (score 0):

Tried with code  and worked fine. It shows Total space, Avaialble space, Used Space

```
df -Ph /boot/|awk 'NR >1 {gsub("%","",$0);print $0}'| awk '{print "Total Space of partition" " "$2"\n""Used space on the disk is" $3"\n""free space on the disk is "$4}'
```

Answer (score 0):

**df** can be called with file/directory name argument, it will then display the amount of disk space available on the file system containing that file/directory, for example:

```
df -h /mnt/san12/office
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdc1             2.0T  2.0T   11G 100% /mnt/san12
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. However, please note that your post seems to mostly reiterate what [this other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/572927/377345) already stated. If you want to add more details or context, please consider submitting an edit suggestion to that answer instead.